# Javascript math.round threshold

Tags: javascript, html

I am keeping track of a timer that I want to trigger at 5 second intervals. The problem is 
that with my test of

```
if (Math.round(time.position) % 5 === 0){do stuff}
```

it triggers too many times. It will trigger for all of the 9.~ decimal values.
How can I have it trigger at 5 second intervals?

```
time:  Object {duration: 149.49, type: "jwplayerMediaTime", position: 9.29} index.html:104
time:  Object {duration: 149.49, type: "jwplayerMediaTime", position: 9.43} index.html:104
time:  Object {duration: 149.49, type: "jwplayerMediaTime", position: 9.54} index.html:104
time:  Object {duration: 149.49, type: "jwplayerMediaTime", position: 9.68} index.html:104
time:  Object {duration: 149.49, type: "jwplayerMediaTime", position: 9.79} index.html:104
time:  Object {duration: 149.49, type: "jwplayerMediaTime", position: 9.92} index.html:104
time:  Object {duration: 149.49, type: "jwplayerMediaTime", position: 10.03} index.html:104
time:  Object {duration: 149.49, type: "jwplayerMediaTime", position: 10.18} index.html:104
time:  Object {duration: 149.49, type: "jwplayerMediaTime", position: 10.29} index.html:104
time:  Object {duration: 149.49, type: "jwplayerMediaTime", position: 10.42} index.html:104
time:  Object {duration: 149.49, type: "jwplayerMediaTime", position: 10.54} index.html:104
time:  Object {duration: 149.49, type: "jwplayerMediaTime", position: 10.68} index.html:104
time:  Object {duration: 149.49, type: "jwplayerMediaTime", position: 10.79} index.html:104
time:  Object {duration: 149.49, type: "jwplayerMediaTime", position: 10.92} index.html:104
time:  Object {duration: 149.49, type: "jwplayerMediaTime", position: 11.04} index.html:104
time:  Object {duration: 149.49, type: "jwplayerMediaTime", position: 11.17}
```

Comment: would `setInterval(function() { ... },5000);` suffice?

Comment: No. This is being triggered by a video player timer.

Comment: You'll have to keep track of the positions you've already covered.

Comment: How could we possibly answer if you don't tell us what `time.position` is?

Answer (score 3):

This will trigger once every 5 seconds I believe.

```
var previousValue = 1;
if(Math.ceil(time.position / 5) !== previousValue) {
    previousValue = Math.ceil(time.position / 5);
}
```

Make sure that you only call the first line once though.